# Spring Security: endpoints with trailing slashes

Tags: spring-security

Suppose I've got an endpoint `/auth/user/{username}` with username as @PathVariable. It's used for DELETE request.

Here's how the requests are handled:

```
http
                .httpBasic(httpSecurityHttpBasicConfigurer -> httpSecurityHttpBasicConfigurer
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                ).csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable()
                ).headers(httpSecurityHeadersConfigurer -> httpSecurityHeadersConfigurer.
                        frameOptions(frameOptionsConfig -> frameOptionsConfig.disable())
                ).authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/auth/**").authenticated()
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
                ).sessionManagement(sessionManagement -> sessionManagement
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                );
```

And here's the method for the endpoint:

```
    @DeleteMapping("/auth/user/{username}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')")
    public ResponseEntity deleteUser(@PathVariable String username) {
        System.out.println("initializing");
        try {
            authService.deleteUser(username);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(Map.of("username", username,
                    "status", "Deleted successfully!"));
        } catch (ResponseStatusException exception) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
    }
```

Obviously, when I send a DELETE request for the endpoint `/auth/user/` I get 404 because I've not definied such an endpoint. Is there any way to make `/auth/user/` (DELETE request) return 403 in an elegant manner?

I achieved what I wanted through:

1. a dummy endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/user", "/user/"}, method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity dummyDelete() {
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
}
```

2. filter chain:
   `.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/auth/user/").denyAll()`

My question is: is there a more elegant way to do this? How would a pro (I suspect that a pro would not even try to handle this??) handle that?